# Rails form check_box_tag parameter passing in array

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox

I am using check_box_tag in my forms with jquery-mobile stylesheeting. My form_tag with check_box_tag works without jquery-mobile, but when I start using the jquery-mobile css and javascript, check_box_tag only allows me to check one option. Here is the code:

```
<%= form_tag(posts_path, :multipart => true) do %>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <legend>Choose terms:</legend>
        <%= check_box_tag name= "agreement[]", value=1, checked = false, :id => "checkbox-1" %>
        <label for="checkbox-1">I agree</label>
        <%= check_box_tag name= "agreement[]", value=2, checked = false, :id => "checkbox-2" %>
        <label for="checkbox-2">I agree without preconditions</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Why can't I select both checkboxes in the UI when jquery-mobile css and javascript is in use? How do I pass an array of parameters to Rails server?

Comment: I found the solution. There is another stackoverflow post regarding this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992094/how-do-i-set-a-unique-id-for-checkboxes-in-a-multi-record-rails-form . I should be using indexes in my name array: so agreement[1] and agreement[2] works instead of just saying agreement[] in the check_box_tag