# JQuery returning element as null

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Ruby on Rails 3.
I have a div id I am trying to hide or show based on the value of a checkbox selected. My script now is unable to get the element by id. It returns null. I tried the input id and name. Both return null.

Here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#device').change(function(event){ 
var hardware = document.getElementById('#survey_hardware_');
if (($(hardware).find("input[value='IP Phones']:checked").length) || ($(hardware).find("input[value='IP PBX Systems']:checked").length))
{
    $('#phonepbx').css('display', 'inline');
}
else
{
    $('#phonepbx').css('display', 'none');
}
});
});
```

This is the rendered HTML question:

```
<div class="row" id="device">
<ul>1.  What IP hardware does your company frequently sell and/or install?  (select all that apply)<br/>
<li style="display:block;"><input id="survey_hardware_" name="survey[hardware][]" type="checkbox" value="IP Phones" /> IP Phones</li>
<li style="display:block;"><input id="survey_hardware_" name="survey[hardware][]" type="checkbox" value="IP PBX Systems" /> IP PBX Systems </li>
<li style="display:block;"><input id="survey_hardware_" name="survey[hardware][]" type="checkbox" value="IP Security/Surveillance Systems" /> IP Security/Surveillance Systems</li>
<li style="display:block;"><input id="survey_hardware_" name="survey[hardware][]" type="checkbox" value="IP infrastructure (cabling, switches...etc.)" /> IP infrastructure (cabling, switches...etc.)</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Summary: The

```
document.getElementById('#survey_hardware_');
```

returns null. I tried #survey[hardware][] and #survey[hardware][0] and all are null. How do I get the element? Thank you (Please don't hate my li styling :)

**Solution**

```
function checkHardware() {
if ($('#device input:checkbox:eq(0)').is(':checked') || $('#device input:checkbox:eq(1)').is(':checked'))
{
    $('#phonepbx').css('display', 'block');
}
```

etc...

Comment: Can you have multiple ids with the same name?

Comment: You shouldn't have more than one element with the same id attribute. This will cause issues when targeting the elements via JS and it is contrary to standards.

Comment: Ya IDs must be unique on document context, your HTML is not valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try without the '#':

```
document.getElementById('survey_hardware_');
```

Or use jQuery directly:

```
$('#survey_hardware_')
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using getElementById at all ? You've got jquery, so use:

```
$("#survey_hardware_").find(
```

Comment: Good idea. I will use this logic.

Answer (score 0):

Something like: (note the new and unique id's)

```
<li style="display:block;"><input id="phones" name="survey[hardware][]" type="checkbox" value="IP Phones" /> IP Phones</li>
<li style="display:block;"><input id="pbx" name="survey[hardware][]" type="checkbox" value="IP PBX Systems" /> IP PBX Systems </li>
<li style="display:block;"><input id="security" name="survey[hardware][]" type="checkbox" value="IP Security/Surveillance Systems" /> IP Security/Surveillance Systems</li>
<li style="display:block;"><input id="infra" name="survey[hardware][]" type="checkbox" value="IP infrastructure (cabling, switches...etc.)" /> IP infrastructure (cabling, switches...etc.)</li>
```

and then use jQuery directly: `$('#new_id_here')` as has already been suggested.

Comment: The questions are in erb file. The HTML is rendered as shown. This is how the question looks in RoR. <li style="display:block;"><%= check_box_tag 'survey[hardware][]', "IP Phones" %> IP Phones</li>

Comment: Sorry I overlooked that bit - have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992094/how-do-i-set-a-unique-id-for-checkboxes-in-a-multi-record-rails-form